# inline CKEditor + AngularJS + dataprocessing

Tags: angularjs, ckeditor

I'm trying to use CKEditor with AngularJS for WYSIWYG editor with data-binding and everything seems to be working well. Extreme configurability helped a lot with our requirement matching.

We are now facing an issue with dirty form.

Problem:

```
model -> abc<br>def\n

ckeditor dataprocessor makes it -> abc<br />def
```

which breaks model & editor content equality and hence causes form to be dirty.

All I want is to set the model with preprocessed value after initialization so the equality stays.

Here is the Angular code for it:

```
app.directive('contenteditable', function() {

return {

        require : 'ngModel',

        link : function(scope, element, attrs, ctrl) {

            var editor = CKEDITOR.inline(element[0]);

            // view -> model

            editor.on('pasteState', function() {

                scope.$apply(function() {

                    ctrl.$setViewValue(editor.getData());
                });

            });

            // model -> view

            ctrl.$render = function() {

                editor.setData(ctrl.$viewValue);

            };

            // load init value from DOM

            ctrl.$render();

        }

    };

});
```

I did quite a bit of searching but didn't find anything apart from turning off the plugin which obviously is not recommended. Any suggestions?

**-- edit --**

in directive:

```
editor.on('instanceReady', function() {
    scope.$apply(function() {
        ctrl.$setViewValue(editor.getData());
        scope.$broadcast('resetContentEditableModel');
    });
});
```

in controller:

```
$scope.$on('resetContentEditableModel', function() {
    $scope.model.value = $scope.form.value;
});
```

This seems to be doing the trick.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that there are two ways:

1. Update your model after loading data to the editor. I don't know Angular, but if this is possible this would be the best choice. CKEditor or browser may try to fix some invalid HTML so it'd be nice to synchronise these things.
2. There's a [`selfClosingEnd` configuration option](http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/api/CKEDITOR.htmlWriter-property-selfClosingEnd) for `htmlwriter` which will allow you to change how self closing tags are rendered.

   ```
   editor.on( 'loaded', function() {
       editor.dataProcessor.writer.selfClosingEnd = '>';
   } );
   ```

Comment: thanks :) first point worked. updated the question lets see if it creates any other issue.